# button URL con id de jquery obtenido de una tabla mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

estoy obteniendo los datos de los clientes en mi base de datos que contiene el numero de tlf de los clientes de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TODO BIEN POR AQUI. y traigo la informacion a una tabla en mi html

```
<? 
/**Consulta a la base de datos**/
$sql = SELECT * from pagos; 

        echo "<div><table class=''id=myTable>";
        echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
                 echo"<th data-placeholder='Buscar ID Pago'> ID Pago </th>";
                 echo"<th data-placeholder='Buscar telefono'> Telefono </th>";
              echo"</tr>";
              echo"</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        /*Y ahora todos los registros */
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

        $tlf_chat=trim($row['tlf']);
        $tlf1chat=str_replace("+","https://wa.me/",$tlf_chat);
       $tlf2chat=str_replace(" ","",$tlf1chat);

        echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td> $row[id_pago] </td>";
                echo"<td> $tlf2chat </td>";
          echo"</tr>";
          echo "</tfoot>";
         echo"</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
```

TODO BIEN HASTA AQUI. Luego, traigo el telefono del cliente le doy un valor id con jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#myTable').dblclick(function(e){

var a=$('td:eq(0)', $(e.target).parents('tr')).text()
a = a.trim()
$("#idpago").text(a)

var a=$('td:eq(1)', $(e.target).parents('tr')).text()
a = a.trim()
$("#chattlf").val(a)

if(a!=""){
$("#md4").modal("show") 
}
})
```

Lo que necesito es que al abrir el modal md4 (que muestra informacion detallada del cliente y su compra), pueda tener un boton que me lleve a chatear con el cliente via whatsapp.

EL PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI en el siguiente boton. Cuando lo presiono simplemente no realiza ninguna opcion.

```
<div class="modal" id="md4"">
  <a  target='_blank' id='chattlf' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'> 
  </i> Chat with <b id='id_pago'></b></a>";
</div>
```

Intenté hacerlo funcionar tambien de otra forma. En vez de usar un id cree una class .chattlf pero tampoco me funciono.

```
<div class="modal" id="md4"">
  <a  target='_blank'  class=' chattlf btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'> 
  </i> Chat with <b id='id_pago'></b></a>";
</div>
```

Soy nueva en esto. Agradezco cualquier aporte!

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el problema **con respecto al código**, ¿quieres saber cómo chatear (si es eso, qué herramienta piensas usar para hacerlo)?, ¿la dificultad es obteniendo el teléfono? Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y explica cuál es el problema y dónde.

Comment: Hola, edite el codigo y añadi donde se encuentra el problema. Es en el boton. En el boton deberia redirigirme a una URL de whatsapp que permite chatear con ese numero. Es decir, el boton deberia redirigirme a una URL como esta: https://wa.me/00000000000 --> donde los ceros representan el numero del cliente. 

Me doy a entender?

Comment: Entiendo. Tienes que ponerle el atributo `href` para que te redirija, por ejemplo: `<a  href="www.google.com" target='_blank' id='chattlf' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'> 
  </i> Chat with <b id='name'></b></a>` Aquí he puesto la dirección de Google, sólo la cambias por la URL que estarás construyendo de algún modo y que redigirá al chat.

Comment: Pienso que el problema esta en con como llamas la funcion ya que lo haces a través del id, prueba intentando llamándolo por la clase, para que no tengas el problema del modal, quita del botón esto .. id='chattlf', y en el botón arega esto: class='btn chattlf btn-success btn-sm '  y en la función cambia #chattlf por .chattlf y nos cuentas si funciona

Comment: A. Cedano, el problema es que la href la estoy obteniendo de un id

Comment: Camilo Kent, lo intente y no realiza ninguna accion mientras no tenga un href. Intente colocar un boton <buttton class='btn chattlf'>prueba</button> y tampoco funciono

Comment: ¿Cómo que la href la estás obteniendo de un id? ¿De qué id, de qué elemento, en qué contexto? Por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica el contexto con claridad en la pregunta proporcionando un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de tu código. No debe ser un problema complicado, pero las explicaciones no son claras. Muchas veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema.

Comment: Listo, añadi mas informacion en mi edicion. Sorry y gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este en este enlace  que deberías verlo como un button, apunta a que habrá WhatsApp en el móvil o en el navegador web y el usuario tenga para escribirle al

```
<div class="modal" id="md4"">
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5667891234" target='_blank' id='chattlf' class='btn btn-success btn-sm>
    <i class='fab fa-whatsapp'></i> 
    Chat with <b id='id_pago'></b>
  </a>
</div>
```

Este es el HTML pero como tu numero de teléfono viene personalizado desde jQuery, que lo traes de una base de datos. Entonces dentro del evento de jQuery de click(), mandas esto

```
$('#chattlf').attr('href','https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+numberchatid)
```

aquí numberchatid es la variable en tu código que tenga el numero de teléfono que traes desde la DB.

Para mas dudas ponga mas preguntas y mas info y lo nuevo que ha hecho en su código para verlo mejor

Comment: Gracias, me salvaste la vida. *-*

Answer (score 1):

En JQuery para guardar algún tipo de info como un datos como el numero de teléfono usa mejor el data-telefono="" y se lee con jquery con el método data(), el cual te permite saber que valor tiene allí sacas el dato del telefono

Lo otro es que estas añadiendo contenido nuevo al DOM y necesitas que el contenido este ahí cuando jquery registra los eventos. En este caso lo mejor es usar el metodo on() en lugar de directamente el metodo que corresponde con el evento de dblclick(), seria algo así:

```
$('body').on('click' , '#myTable' , function(e){
  // el codigo del evento aqui
}
```

de esta manera puedes manipular elementos añadidos al DOM después de que jquery haya usado su método ready() al inicio de la carga de tu script

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, gracia spor el aporte

Comment: hola que tal? estoy intentando hacer lo que me dices pero me está costando llevarlo a cabo? puedes ayudarme? Ya agregue el codigo que me brindaste anteriormente. Que seguiría?